# How on/live event in JQuery actually works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to write a plugin, that will bind some loading animation to pictures before they are loaded from the server. It works fine, except some cases. I mean changing of the DOM structure. The logic of my plugin is:

```
(function( window ){

'use strict';

var $ = window.jQuery;
var console = window.console;
var hasConsole = typeof console !== 'undefined';

var methods = {
    // plugin initialization
    init : function( options ) {
        return this.each(function(){
            methods._applyImagepreloader.apply( this, options);
        });
    },
    // working with each object
    _applyImagepreloader: function() {
        // if has class imagepreloader, do nothing
        if ($(this).hasClass('imagepreloader'))
            return;
        // if the image has determined size
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        $(this)
            .clone()
            .attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .addClass('imagepreloader')
            .insertAfter(this);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).load(function(){
            $(this).next('.imagepreloader').remove();
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    }
};

$.fn.imagepreloader = function( options ) {
    return methods.init.apply( this, options );
};

})( window );
```

Now, when the page is being updated by AJAX and new image tags appear, my plugin does not work. I made an investigation and learned, that the DOM mutation events can help me, but, as I understood, they are not supported by all browsers. Moreover, I can catch changin of DOM structure, using setinterval, but I guess It is not the best practice. So, maybe the issue has been already solved in JQuery on/live events. I wonder, how they work. How they can catch an appearance of new DOM elements?

Comment: The issue is not to do with the plugin code *per se* but how/when it is invoked (or not invoked) on the img nodes in question. You need to be sure to invoke the plugin on existing img nodes at page load, then whenever new img nodes are inserted.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, but how can I determine that new img nodes were inserted?

Comment: Are you in charge of the code that performs the insertion? If so, then invoke the plugin in that code.

Comment: Guess, it is not the best practice to call the plugin twice. But if I don't find another solution, I will try that.

Comment: You can invoke it as many times as necessary. It's not necessarily bad practice. After all, you wouldn't think twice about calling built-in jQuery methods many times over. The plugin includes the means of rejecting elements on which it is already invoked so you needn't worry about multiple invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use event delegation with `on`, event is always attached to a static element which is not going to be loaded dynamically

```
$("#Container").on('click','#dynamicallyAddedChildOfContainer',function(){...});
```

For example `#Container` in above example is the container which is present in DOM and you are adding `#dynamicallyAddedChildOfContainer` dynamically, Now when you click on dynamically added element, the event bubble's up to the container and that is where the event is triggered.

More on event delegation -

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Thanks, pXL. Helpful post.